# Update-AzureRmVmss : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to change the password of VMSS (Service Fabric Cluster nodes) via Powershell.
The Process of the chnage password of VMSS come with the following error.
After error come the password changed but VMSS state showing failed,

```
Update-AzureRmVmss : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError
ErrorMessage: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'ServiceProfilerAgent'. Error message: "Failed to launch diagnostic agent. The agent output: $Unpacking resources...
Executing Service Profiler Agent version 1.0.41004.1 with arguments: --mode AzureVMExtension --vmextsettings 1.settings
Welcome to Service Profiler - to exit the program press 'Ctrl+C'.
Initializing agent...
Loading settings from cloud storage. Settings name: default
The settings file 'default-settings.json' was not found in storage.
Account name: appperformance
Container name: sp-agent-settings
Blob name: default-settings.json
There was a problem loading the settings. Failed to load settings from cloud storage.
".
StartTime: 6/4/2017 10:58:11 AM
EndTime: 6/4/2017 10:58:16 AM
OperationID: a0bfeb48-2da0-4dea-8e73-9137d11b0351
Status: Failed
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -Name $vmssName -Virtua ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-AzureRmVmss], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Common.ComputeCloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.UpdateAzureRmVmss
```

I have successfully changed the password of VMSS scale set but this error comes.
My VMSS state showing fails but still my service fabric Cluster running.

Here are the commands i have used to changed the password of VMSS.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$vmssName = "node"
$vmssResourceGroup = "RG"
publicConfig = @{"UserName" = "username"}
$privateConfig = @{"Password" = "Password"}
$extName = "VMAccessAgent"
$publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
$vmss = Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Name $extName -Publisher $publisher -Setting $publicConfig -ProtectedSetting $privateConfig -Type $extName -TypeHandlerVersion "2.0" -AutoUpgradeMinorVersion $true
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -Name $vmssName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Comment: VMSS instance OS is Linux or windows?

Comment: windows .......

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message, could you please run this script again? How many instances in your VMSS, have you enable autoscaling?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the profiler agent cannot connect to the storage account to download the settings file.

Can you check if the storage account still exists or the storage connection has changed?

If anything has changed, you can update the storage account in https://www.azureserviceprofiler.com/  and re-run the deployment script with the updated storage account.

If you decide to stop the profiling, you can also remove the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceProfiler/ ServiceProfilerAgent extension.

Hope this helps! :)